# How does a Homebrew-installed Emacs get the same PATH variable as set in the shell?

Tags: startup, homebrew, path

I am running homebrew on an M2 Mac mini under macOS Ventura.

I use `Emacs.app` from the `railwaycat/emacsmacport/emacs-mac` cask and when I check in Emacs the inherited `PATH` environment variable, Emacs returns something with `/opt/homebrew/bin` at the beginning.

I start Emacs.app via double-clicking, so I assume no terminal shell gets started for this. (Plus I do not use the `exec-path-from-shell` package in Emacs.)

Where in the startup process does homebrew's `bin` directory get added? I looked at:

- `/etc/paths.d`, but homebrew doesn't add any entry there.
- `~/.zprofile` and homebrew *does* add stuff in there. This stuff shows up in Emacs (when I check in Emacs via `getenv` `PATH`). However, I have no idea *why* this happens (because, as mentioned above, no shell should get started.)

Comment: Which GUI apps do have Homebrew in their PATH (and how do you verify this) ?

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for chiming in! I have added a footnote to my question to explain.

Comment: How do you start Emacs, which file do you run or double-click? How do you check PATH? By using `(getenv "PATH")` in the scratch buffer or by running a shell within emacs? In the first case, did you chenck the Emacs init file?

Comment: Also, is the path you get in Emacs identical to the path you have in Terminal?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is just run a shell command from within Emacs itself. M-! and then 'echo $PATH' at the Shell command prompt. That'll let you know what Emacs sees when you start it.

Comment: @TraneFrancks (getenv "PATH“) does this.

Comment: @TraneFrancks that will get more than the getenv call as the shells initfiles will  be loaded and they can change things

Comment: @nohillside The path in Emacs is the same as in `zsh` when I don't set a `.zshrc` file. Also, I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/libexec/path_helper`?

Comment: Also, if you change PATH in .zprofile and then restart Emacs, does the change show up in Emacs as well?